# loading and running jsp file error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to create a new jsp-file in eclipse
I installed tomcat server and created new dynamic web content.

now i want to create a new jsp file, but each time i try to create the jsp file eclipse give me the warning message shown on the image posted below.

please let me know how to load and run the jsp files using eclipse correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be creating JSPs in a non-Java eclipse project and hence this warning is coming.

To run a jsp file you need a container like Tomcat. You can configure Tomcat under Runtime in eclipse. Follow this link to learn more about configuring Tomcat with eclipse:

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html

Comment: my tomcat server is already configured as recommended in the link u posted

Comment: The "RemoteSystemTempFiles" project is not an Eclipse Java Project nor one that has the features of an Eclipse Java Project.